# Mutate Function Changed?

Tags: r

I want to get the rowsum of my data set by using dplyr::mutate function. My data set likes below:

```
    Item    Week1  Week2   Week3   Week4  Week5
1   9023    838     82      36      7       8
2   9682    860     106     41      12     10
3   10998   351     101     15      11      6
4   12227   5       63      6       1       0
5   12306   142     1       1       1       5

> class(all_weeks_sales)
[1] "grouped_df" "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
```

My code is:

```
dataset1  <- dataset1 %>% mutate(total = rowSums(.[2:6]))
```

But I get the error

```
"Error: Column `Total` must be length 1 (the group size), not 332"
```

My data set has 332 rows. I checked the manual for `mutate` function and don't know what is the problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Looks like you need `dplyr::mutate(total = rowSums(.[2:6]))` if you have loaded `plyr` also in the env as `plyr` also have function `mutate` which can mask

Comment: Please post a dataset (the output of `dput(your_data)`) which, when run with the included code, reproduces the error. When I run the code after recreating the table you display as text with `read.table` I get the expected output with no error.

Comment: @akrun When I use `all_weeks_sales  %>% dplyr::mutate(total = rowSums(.[2:6]))`, I got same error. I use `library(dplyr)` in my first row of code.

Comment: Can you check whether your dataset is `data.frame` or `matrix` or some of the columns are `list`

Comment: @akrun I have added the result of the class of my data set.

Comment: The class output says your data.frame is grouped, so you need to `ungroup()` first.  For a grouped df, mutate calculates a result for each group, not the entire data.frame. The error is saying your rowSums output must match the group size, which it doesn't. If you ungroup it, you don't need to worry about matching group size.

Comment: Or another option is to call `data.frame` before the `mutate` so as to remove all the attributes

Comment: @IceCreamToucan The reason for this only because it is a `grouped_tibble`?

Comment: The rationale for @IceCreamToucan's suggestion is that your use of `.` in your mutate goes outside of `dplyr`'s grouping and returns the entire frame (of 332 rows) instead of the per-group rows (1 for the first group, apparently).

Comment: @IceCreamToucan Yeah, you are right. I used `group_by` before and combine different data sets by `full_join()`. I never `ungroup()` it. Now no error occurred after I ungroup it. Thank you!